# ElevatedButton and Switch in an Column, render issues

Tags: flutter

I'm having an problem when using an Switch widget and a ElevatedButton in the same column. The purpose of the switch is to switch between dark and light mode. If I remove either the switch or elevatedbutton widget everything works but not if i have both, then i get an RenderFlex error.

A RenderFlex overflowed by 99244 pixels on the bottom.

The code:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text("Logout"),
      onPressed: () async {
        SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await localStorage.remove('token');
        await localStorage.remove('rawSchedule');
        await localStorage.setBool('loggedIn', false);
        //Push to home screen
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
      },
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Text("Dark theme"),
        Switch(
          value: _darkModeSwitch,
          onChanged: (value) async {
            SharedPreferences localStorage =
            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            if (localStorage.getBool('theme')) {
              localStorage.setBool('theme', false);
            } else {
              localStorage.setBool('theme', true);
            }
            //Change the theme
            getThemeManager(context).toggleDarkLightTheme();

            setState(() {
              _darkModeSwitch = value;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitxY.png)

The whole class:
https://pastebin.com/0AFc0Hbc

The drawer is the used on every scaffold pages as an endDrawer

Comment: There must be other widgets on your screen and when you add both there is no space on your screen to fit both? My guess is due to other widgets on the screen there is space just for one.

Comment: It's in an drawer and there is no problem to add more buttons or more switches. The only problem is when there is button and switch togheter. Updated the post now with an link to pastbin with the whole class. https://pastebin.com/0AFc0Hbc

Comment: I tested your code from pastebin.com and did not get any errors.

Comment: hmm strange. Even if you use it as an endDrawer in some scaffold page?

Comment: Yes, drawer or enddrawer both worked. Please see the code I used to test - https://pastebin.com/iKcan7zT You may run it in dartpad if you like.